# Setting classpath to use JSON simple

Tags: java, json, classpath, json-simple

I am trying to use the JSON simple library, but I just can'e execute my program with it.

I am trying to compile this way:

`$ javac -classpath json.jar TestClass.java` (json.rar is the json-simple file)

And it compiles ok. But I'm having trouble running it. This is how I am trying to run the program:

`$ java -classpath json.jar:. TestClass`

And I get the following error: `Error: Could not find or load main class TestClass`

But the file IS there. After an ls, this show up:

`DBImporter.class  json-simple-1.1.1.jar  TestClass.class  testfile2.txt
DBImporter.java   output.txt             TestClass.java
json.jar          resource.db            testfile.txt`

I'm searching on the internet for hours, and no solution works for me. I don't know if this is relevant, but this is my TestClass

```
import java.io.*;
import org.json.simple.*;

public class TestClass{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to run the program using the following command:

`$ java -cp json.jar:./ TestClass`

Putting a slash after the dot. I'm not sure why it worked, if anyone know the explanation it would be nice, mainly because I haven't seen this solution anywhere when searching for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
java -classpath json.jar;. TestClass
```

Class:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.json.*;

    public class TestClass{

        public static void main(String[] args){

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
     System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }
```

Directory Structure : G:\Mudit\Test - inside this test directory I have put json.jar and TestClass.java and I am running the following commands:

Compile :**javac -classpath json.jar TestClass.java**
Run: **java -classpath json.jar;. TestClass**

Output: Hello
Hope this clarifies.

Comment: When trying this I receive:

`Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include: [with a bunch of options here]` and in the very last line `bash: TestClass: No such file or directory`

But since I'm using mysys shell (which accept linux commands) I tried `$ java -classpath json.jar:. TestClass` instead, but the response was `Error: Could not find or load main class TestClass`.

Comment: No. Here, this is all that shows up when I tried the commands: http://i.imgur.com/uRjiFrz.png

Comment: $ java -classpath json.jar;. TestClass . instead of using :(colon) use ;(semicolon), let me know if does not work.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried both already. You can see in the screenshot, in the second command I use the semicolon, and in the third one, the colon. :(

Comment: I am not able to see the screenshot.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It is in this link ( i.imgur.com/uRjiFrz.png ). Anyway, when I try with semicolon it doensn't recognize the command and says `bash: TestClass: No such file or directory`. When I try with colon, it says `Error: Could not find or load main class TestClass`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77735/discussion-between-mudit-and-fmp).